# How to inject bytecode to a compiled java program without using tools?

Tags: java, bytecode, code-injection, bytecode-manipulation

I want to learn how I can create an injectable piece of java bytecode, and inject it into an already compiled java program so it will run when the said program is executed.
It doesn't have to be dynamic and in runtime, just given a compiled java program inject additional code into it.

Now, I know there are many existing tools for this, like Javassist and ASM. But the act itself isn't my goal, I want to learn how its done, so I want to learn how to do this ***without these tools***.

For example: How to strip excess code from the source bytecode, where to inject it into the target code, etc.

The best answer would be one or more simple pieces of source or pseudo-code.
After learning and successfully doing this I'm going to start searching info on how to do this to Linux executable binaries, so adding in more information on that way would also be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: All things considered - javassist is open source, so I'm not sure why you're not studying that source code instead.

Comment: There are several reasons for that, javassist has a lot of functionality and a huge code base. CtClass for example is over 1500 lines of code. What I'm after is a small fraction which I haven't been able to find in the code base yet. So I figured someone may already know this and show me the right direction, along with looking for the needle in the haystack I tried asking about it here.

Comment: So I suppose a better question would be, why would you presume that something like injecting bytecode would be anything less than that?  Perhaps it could be if it weren't decoupled, but I personally believe that reading that source code is likely your best start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javassist is essentially decompiling and compiling the code, that is why there is a lot of code there.
And you won't find the type code injection you are looking for in javassist. So "Go read javassist" is a rather stupid suggestion.

If you want to put your code into an specific place(for instance in the start or constructor)
you can see how to find the spot by reading JVM docs.

However as Antimony mentioned, you are looking for bytecode knowledge, so here it is:
http://arhipov.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/java-bytecode-fundamentals.html

If you want to inject a piece of bytecode,you can just find the start of your main() and paste the code there. It will be 200-300 LOC MAX.

With linux binaries it is much easier, read this:
http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf

Answer (score 2):

First off, Java classfiles are essentially immutable once loaded, so what you're really asking is how to create and modify classfiles by hand.

The answer is to read the JVM specification. That's how I got started with bytecode. After reading the specs, I wrote a couple simple classfiles by hand in a hex editor and played around with it to see how things worked. Of course, that's not practical for normal usage, so I later wrote an assembler. It's not that hard.

Incidentally, [the source code for my assembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau/tree/master/Krakatau/assembler) is only around 1k lines of code, so it's a lot less to sort through than Javaassist.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is done by reading the bytecode (or Linux executable), transforming it into some form of Intermediate Representation (IR), perform additional transformation on the IR, and convert it back into the original format.

If you transform the IR back into Java source code, you will get a decompiler for Java. If you perform analysis on the IR, manipulate it (addition, removal, rewriting, etc.) and convert the transformed IR back to the bytecode format, you will get what you described.

For detailed algorithms on how to convert bytecode to an IR, you can refer to Section 3.3 of http://suif.stanford.edu/~jwhaley/papers/mastersthesis.pdf and Section 3 of https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse501/01wi/project/sable-thesis.pdf